# from "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:" to "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé:"

Tags: python, windows, file, operating-system, chmod

When I run this code:

```
def register_json(path, _dict):
    from json import dump
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        dump(_dict, f)

json_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\RT Forms\debug.json"
my_new_dict = {"yolo":"swag"}
register_json(json_path, my_new_dict)
```

I get this error message:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\RT Forms\\debug.json'`

So I tried to change the rights of my file:

```
from os import chmod
json_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\RT Forms\debug.json"
chmod(json_path, 0o777)
```

and now I get this error:
`PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\RT Forms\\debug.json'`

Is there a solution to give the right during the creation of the file maybe ? (Yes, I am the one who create the file, the entire folder with pyinstaller and HM NSIS edit to have a .nsi which create this folder. When you execute the .exe it will create the .json file).

Comment: 1. You should use double slash '\\' in windows path. 2. Non-admin users have read-only access to the "Program files" folders by default.

Comment: @viilpe 
1. You're right. 
2. But I am the one which create files in this folder and windows doesn't stop me from doing it during the runtime, can't I adapt the rights ? Is there a good place to stock information in .json ?

Comment: saving data in "Program Files" is a bad practice. You better do it in AppData or another user folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @viilpe, I am registering data in `C:\\ProgramData` now. (it could have been AppData).

So it was just a permission problem from `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\` folder, don't try to change something in it after the installation of your application because you had the administrator rights, you won't have it anymore.